# document undefined using node.js in google dialogflow fullfilment (server side)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, nightmare

```
function readrequestfromdb(agent){
  var links = [];
  var requestbooks = [];
  var books = admin.database().ref( 'data/request' );
  const Nightmare = require( 'nightmare' );
  const nightmare = Nightmare();
  const url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/';
  return books.once( "value", function( data ){
    var _data = data.val();
    for( var key in _data ){
      var book = _data[key];
      var name = book.name;
      var author = book.author;
      var res = `name is ${name} and author is ${author}`;
      requestbooks.push( res );
      nightmare
        .goto( url )
        .wait( 'body' )
        .click( 'button._2AkmmA._29YdH8' )
        .type( 'input.LM6RPg', name )
        .click( 'button.vh79eN' )
        .wait( 'div.bhgxx2' )
        .evaluate( () => document.querySelectorAll( 'a._2cLu-l' )[0].href )
        .end()
        .then( link => {
          console.log( link );
          links.push( link );
        } )
        .catch( err => {
          console.log( err );
        } );

    }

    return agent.add( text );
  } );
}
```

I am trying to use the above code for web scraping and accessing document is given in the nightmare documentation. what is the solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although we can take a few guesses at what is going on, we don't know what problem you're encountering. Please update your question to include any error messages you're getting, what the expected outcome is, and what is actually happening. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am trying to to do web scrapping using nightmare. i am going to extract few flipkart links from worldwideweb and use those in my response. it is throwing out a warning 'document' is not defined.